# leer parametros de una aplicacion de consola

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

una pregunta sencilla, cual sería el metodo para leer valores de configuracion de una aplicacion de consola. 
Mi idea inicial era crear un txt y poner alli valores, supongamos algo asi como

RevisarTodo= True;

Luego, recuperar en la aplicacion esa linea y usarla como parametro.

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna técnica mas avanzada para hacer eso, pero con la condición que no puedo recompilar la dll, es decir, que sea algo que el usuario pueda cambiar sin tener que codificar de nuevo.

Comment: Pero a que te refieres con reconfigurar, yo diria por que no guardarlo en un JSON seria mas facil y mas moldeable

Comment: Y cual seria el problema de la tecnica esa? eso se usa y mucho en muchos tipos de aplicaciones. En general depende la version en que compiles tu .net, tenes versiones mas avanzadas de archivos de texto que podes leer tranquilamente sin tener que reconstruir tu aplicacion.

Comment: @EdgarVazquez pobre el que tenga que reescribir el json a mano

Comment: @gbianchi si es a mano si pobre, pero como el decia que se leeria , debe ser mas facil y estructural, por eso lo recomende :D pero si llega a perderse si pobre :/

Comment: @gbianchi no hay ningun problema, sólo preguntaba por si me perdí de algo "nuevo", que se yo, por ahi apareció alguna vulnerabilidad con los archivos de texto, o el visual studio saco alguna herramienta para hacer eso.... no se, solo preguntaba

Comment: @NioDeTark porque aceptaste una respuesta que no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En inglés:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51379b07-7fd3-495a-b2bc-830462fe0fa1/visual-basic-console-application-with-arguments?forum=vbgeneral

En su codigo, necesito algo como asi

```
  Dim clArgs() As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Cuando arranca el programa del console, Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() contiene los strings.  Por ejemplo:

```
c:\>VayaALaLuna -dia=hoy -personas=3

clArgs(0) = VayaALaLuna
clArgs(1) = -dia=hoy
clArgs(2) = -personas=3
```

De alli, es fácil parsear la información.

El enlace explica como usar parametros con VisualStudio.

EDIT: Para leer información de un archivo (semejante a un web.config pero llamado app.config), puede usar

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings()

<configuration>
[snip]
   <appSettings>
     <add key="pais" value="Transylvania" />
   </appSettings>
[snip]
</configuration>

Dim pais as String
pais = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("pais")
```

Fin del edit

Comment: no habla de argumentos por linea de comandos, habla de tener parametros para su programa. Una pena, porque es una linda respuesta. Tal vez si no hay una pregunta al respecto, podrias armarla?

Comment: tiene razón el comentario de @gbianchi

Comment: Tu edit es la respuesta. Podrias agregar eso, como se guarda el archivo, como se modifica el mismo y todas esas cosas?

Comment: dutson, donde pongo eso?

Comment: En un archivo llamado app.config en la carpeta donde está el programa.